# Скрыть элемент при печати

Tags: css

```
var widget = $('<div/>', {id: 'asterisk-popup', class: 'popup-box noprint', style: 'min-height: 180px;'});
```

Есть вот такое окошко в документе. Скрипт его периодически то показывает `show()`, то скрывает `fadeOut()`.

В стилях записано так

```
@media print {
    .noprint { display: none; }
}
```

Но в общем то не работает такая связка. При печати всё равно окошко лезет. 
Я скриптом захардкодил, чтобы окно к DOM не прицеплялось на определенных страницах, но может можно проще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline-стиль, навешиваемый скриптом, приоритетнее стиля из css-класса, поэтому следует использовать `!important`:

```
@media print {
  .noprint {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```